# xml data to pdf form vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

net. i just get the database values. Database values are converted to xml format using for nested keyword. i m having the proper xml file. now i need to bind this xml data into PDF form. In pdf form i m having one table. i need to fill this table using xml data. anybody helpme.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) the can transform your XML to a PDF.

Alternatively, use one of the [*many* .NET PDF](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=xsl-fo%20.net%20library#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=pdf%20.net%20library&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=9df504d89eb18661) libraries to generate a PDF directly from either the database values or the XML.